# What type of exception it raises when database doesn't exist in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I want to handle the exception when database doesn't exist. I'm not able to find to find out what type of exception ActiveRecord raises when database not found.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer myself, it raises `ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError` exception.

Thanks.